# How to increment elements of a list using using append and dolist in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm trying to increment elements in a `list` by creating a new `list` to which I would `append` incremented elements of an old `list` in `dolist` loop.

First I tried this and it didn't work:

```
(defun increment-list(old-list)
    (setq new-list (list))
    (when (listp old-list)
        (dolist (x old-list) (append new-list (+ x 1)))
        (print new-list)
    )
)
```

Then I thought that maybe `list` can only be appended with another `list`, so I changed `dolist` to look like this:

```
(dolist (x old-list) (append new-list (list (+ x 1))))
```

Both solutions left gave the same result - `new-list` was `NIL`.

Currently, I'm using `push`, but it makes a reversed `list`. I could reverse it again, but it seems to be an unnecessary complication.

I have also found other solutions which I could use. However, I'm eager to find out why `append` doesn't work here because according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6440525) it should.

Comment: APPEND doesn't modify a list.  It returns a new one.  In your case, you'd do `(setq new-list (append new-list (+ x 1)))`.  This requires traversing the entire `new-list` each time though.  It would be more efficient to collect the list in reverse order and reverse it at the end.  In fact, the common way to do that would be `(let ((new-list '())) (dolist (x list (nreverse new-list)) (push (1+ x) new-list)))`.   (Note the third element in the argument list to `dolist`, and you may want to look at the function `1+`.

Comment: It works, I wasn't aware of the possibility of using third argument in `dolist`. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you aware of the [`mapcar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) function that can reduce your function body to `(mapcar #'1+ old-list)`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but like I said, I wanted to do this using `dolist`.